Unable to get trace_id and span_id to show up in jsonTemplateLayout using opentelemetry-log4j-context-data-2.17-autoconfigure
I am trying to get the trace and span IDs to show up in my logging. Reading https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/instrumentation/log4j/log4j-context-data/log4j-context-data-2.17/library-autoconfigure I followed the example and can get trace and span IDs to show up when using the PatternLayout but when I switch to using the below it doesn't work and just shows a string literal instead
<Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
  <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:EcsLayout.json">
    <EventTemplateAdditionalField key="traceID" value="${ctx:trace_id}">
  </JsonTemplateLayout>
</Console>

I've also tried $${ctx:trace_id}, ${mdc:trace_id}, $${mdc:trace_id}, ${json:mdc:trace_id}, and $${json:mdc:trace_id} and it still doesn't work.

Looks like I was just blind and I didn't need to add anything for it to already be picked up in the json output
